# What is the correct way to get the sum of two string inputs using Java with HTML?

Tags: java, html

I am attempting to make an HTML page where the user inputs 2 numbers as strings, clicks submit, and the sum is displayed. I screwed up something along the way while parsing and I am not sure how to correct it. How do I fix this issue?

```
java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
    java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:461)
    basicaddition.BasicAddition.processRequest(BasicAddition.java:42)
```

The code:

```
    String EmptyError = "";
    String FirstNumber = request.getParameter("FirstNumber");
    String SecondNumber = request.getParameter("SecondNumber");

    float firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(FirstNumber);
    float secondNumber = Float.parseFloat(SecondNumber);

    if(FirstNumber.isBlank() && SecondNumber.isBlank())
    {
      EmptyError = "There is no sum";
    }

   else {
            try {
                 firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(FirstNumber);

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                EmptyError = "Value is not a number";
            }

            try {
                secondNumber = Float.parseFloat(SecondNumber);

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                EmptyError = "Value is not a number";
            }


        }

      Float Result = firstNumber + secondNumber;

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet BasicAddition</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("<h1>Returns the sum of two numbers, ");
        out.println("</h1>");

        out.println("<input type='text' name='FirstNumber' />");
        out.println(EmptyError);

        out.println("<input type='text' name='SecondNumber' />");
        out.println(EmptyError);

        out.println("<input type='submit' value='Get the sum' />");
        out.println(EmptyError);
        out.println(Result);


        out.println("<h1>Servlet BasicAddition at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

Comment: could be because of empty string parsing on line 
float firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(FirstNumber);
    float secondNumber = Float.parseFloat(SecondNumber);

Comment: Unless the entire purpose of this is to learn about the Servlet API, I strongly recommend going with a sensible framework like Spring MVC that handles all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing you're trying to parse the numbers before the condition!

```
float firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(FirstNumber);
float secondNumber = Float.parseFloat(SecondNumber);
```

Those two lines throw an exception because FirstNumber and SecondNumber are not a valid number!

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` condition, you have to use 'OR' operator. Otherwise at least one condition is `false` it jumps to `else`. you have to remove `String` to `float` conversion before the `if` statement. Check below code:

```
    String EmptyError = "";

    String FirstNumber = request.getParameter("FirstNumber");
    String SecondNumber = request.getParameter("SecondNumber");

    float firstNumber, secondNumber;

    if (FirstNumber.isBlank() || SecondNumber.isBlank()) {
        EmptyError = "There is no sum";
    } else {
        //Rest of the code
    }
```